Strange display when double clicking an image
Linux is always full of surprises. :-)
I am using Thunar as my file manager. (I know it is for XFCE.)
When I double click an image, I get this.


You've not provided release details; but it looks like JPG files are handled by firefox on your system.   I just started thunar on my box (I'm currently logged into a Lubuntu/LXQt session) and on my box (my release) a random JPG was opened by lximage-qt which is appropriate for my setup. Did you intentionally setup firefox to handle opened JPGs?  (I don't know what defaults would be normal for you unstated release)

@guiverc Ubuntu-Mate 24.04

@ guivercI set the default program to Gimp for .jpg and .png files. Looks like my problem is fixed.

If it's fixed, please feel free to write up your own answer outlining why & what you did to resolve issue..

I set the default program to Gimp for .jpg and .png files.
